# Oracle - produce unique rows for each unique column value and convert rows to columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle 11g R2 is in use. This is my source table:

```
ASSETNUM    WONUM   WODATE     TYPE1    TYPE2   LOCATION
--------------------------------------------------------
W1          1001    2015-10-10  N       N       loc1
W1          1002    2015-10-02  Y       N       loc2
W1          1003    2015-10-04  Y       N       loc2
W1          1004    2015-10-05  N       Y       loc2
W1          1005    2015-10-07  N       Y       loc2
W2          2001    2015-10-11  N       N       loc1
W2          2002    2015-10-03  Y       N       loc2
W2          2003    2015-10-02  Y       N       loc2
W2          2004    2015-10-08  N       Y       loc3
W2          2005    2015-10-06  N       Y       loc3
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8ee297/1

I want to write a query to get following data:

```
ASSETNUM    LATEST      LOCATION for   LATEST_WODATE_FOR   LATEST_WODATE_FOR    
            WODATE      LATEST WODATE   TYPE1=Y             TYPE2=Y 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
W1          2015-10-10   loc1          2015-10-04          2015-10-07
W2          2015-10-11   loc1          2015-10-03          2015-10-08
```

I need a similar resultset with only one row for each unique value in ASSETNUM.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analytic functions to the rescue.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8ee297/4

```
select assetnum,
       wodate,
       wonum,
       location,
       last_type1_wodate,
       last_type2_wodate
 from(select assetnum,
             wodate,
             wonum,
             location,
             rank() over (partition by assetnum order by wodate desc) rnk_wodate,
             max(case when type1 = 'Y' then wodate else null end) 
               over (partition by assetnum) last_type1_wodate,
             max(case when type2 = 'Y' then wodate else null end)
               over (partition by assetnum) last_type2_wodate
        from t)
   where rnk_wodate = 1
```

Walking through what that's doing

- `rank() over (partition by assetnum order by wodate desc)` takes all the rows for a particular `assetnum` and sorts them by `wodate`.  The predicate on the outside `where rnk_wodate = 1` returns just the most recent row.  If there can be ties, you may want to use `dense_rank` or `row_number` in place of `rank` depending on how you want ties to be handled.
- `max(case when type1 = 'Y' then wodate else null end) over (partition by assetnum)` takes all the rows for a particular `assetnum` and finds the value that maximizes the `case` expression.  That will be the last row where `type1 = 'Y'` for that `assetnum`.

Comment: This was great! Thank you for this answer. It fits perfectly with my requirements! I just had to add `location`  in the select query and it worked fine. This is definitely my preferred answer even though it's a bit difficult to understand. Thanks a lot for the walkthrough!

Answer (score 2):

I think the conceptually easiest approach to this is to simply view your problem as 3 separate queries, each of which is doing a `GROUP BY` to obtain some specific thing (the latest `WODATE`, the latest `WODATE` for Type1, and the latest `WODATE` for Type2).  These queries can easily be joined together to give you the output you want.

```
SELECT T.ASSETNUM, t1.LATEST_WODATE, T.LOCATION, t2.LATEST_WODATE_TYPE1,
    t3.LATEST_WODATE_TYPE2
FROM T INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ASSETNUM, MAX(WODATE) AS LATEST_WODATE
    FROM T
    GROUP BY ASSETNUM
) t1
ON T.ASSETNUM = t1.ASSETNUM AND T.WODATE = t1.LATEST_WODATE
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ASSETNUM, MAX(WODATE) AS LATEST_WODATE_TYPE1
    FROM T
    WHERE TYPE1 = 'Y'
    GROUP BY ASSETNUM
) t2
ON T.ASSETNUM = t2.ASSETNUM
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ASSETNUM, MAX(WODATE) AS LATEST_WODATE_TYPE2
    FROM T
    WHERE TYPE2 = 'Y'
    GROUP BY ASSETNUM
) t3
ON T.ASSETNUM = t3.ASSETNUM
```

Click the link below for a running demo:

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8ee297/15)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you are right, conceptually this answer is the easiest to follow.

Comment: The other answer, even though a bit more difficult to follow, suits my requirement better. I have marked the other answer as the accepted answer. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Using aggregate function [first](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions074.htm#SQLRF00641),

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8ee297/18)

**Query**:

```
select assetnum,
       max(wodate),
       max(wonum) keep (dense_rank first order by wodate desc) wonum,
       max(case when type1 = 'Y' then wodate end) last_type1_wodate,
       max(case when type2 = 'Y' then wodate end) last_type2_wodate
from t
group by
      assetnum
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8ee297/18/0)**:

```
| ASSETNUM |               MAX(WODATE) | WONUM |         LAST_TYPE1_WODATE |         LAST_TYPE2_WODATE |
|----------|---------------------------|-------|---------------------------|---------------------------|
|       W1 | October, 10 2015 00:00:00 |  1001 | October, 04 2015 00:00:00 | October, 07 2015 00:00:00 |
|       W2 | October, 11 2015 00:00:00 |  2001 | October, 03 2015 00:00:00 | October, 08 2015 00:00:00 |
```

`(dense_rank) (first) (order by wodate desc)`
`(     2    ) (  3  ) (          1         )`

1. order the dates in descending order for each assetnum(as specified in GROUP BY clause).
2. assign dense_rank to them.
3. select only first record.

In your sample data, this will select only single record. corresponding to latest date.
But you cannot directly select wonum, since you are using GROUP BY clause. So you have to use a aggregare function, which can be MIN , MAX , SUM, etc. It is there only for semantic purpose.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please elaborate on this query? I'm not sure why `max(wonum)` is used here.

Comment: Thanks, how do I add `location` in this query?

Comment: max(location) keep (dense_rank first order by wodate desc)

Comment: Awesome! This is also a great solution. Thank you.